# Can't rotate and scale anything

Tags: scale

After I animate one UV texture on plane with AnimAll add-on, I can't scale and rotate any object,in object mode.Only can scale and rotate if I select all in edit mod.
Please help
[image: This is my model]

[image: I see this if i start scaling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe deactivate the *Manipulate Center Points* option?

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is solve my problem...