# Can't scale biezer curve object after editing object in Blender 2.8

Tags: scale, bezier-curves

I can't scale a bezier curve object in Blender 2.8.  The thing is I was able to do this when I created the object.   I worked with it a little bit and it just stop scaling.   See animation below

**I know people have had similar issues and they say "deactivate the Manipulate Center Points"**  [deactivate manipulate center points](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134185/cant-rotate-and-scale-anything)
But I can't find that in Blender 2.8

[image: Scale issue]

Here's how I created the object from the beginning.

[image]

I'm running Blender 2.8 Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit.

Comment: I am able to only scale the single control point if deselecting it and selecting the handles - but if selecting two or more control points, then I can scale them. I am wondering if you did your scaling with more than one selected when you made your shape there?

Comment: @CraigDJones I made my starting shape using the Curve - Polygon ab (included in the curve extra nodes plugin) and chose 5 sides and 3D then I  selected all points and subdivided them.

Comment: @CraigDJones I included another animation showing how I created the object.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how vertices in curves work: they are defined by a center point, where the curve goes through, and two handles which can be on the same axis or not.

The handles define the direction of the curve while exiting the vertex and their easing, just like a keyframe in the Graph editor. The central point is just a positional reference, like a normal vertex in a mesh, so it doesn't have a scale (it's a point: it's a "0D" element). The reason why you can scale multiple centerpoints is that they behave like vertices in a mesh, so if you scale them up they increase their distance from the median point.

In this gif you can see that you can scale the vertex up if you select 2 of them or you scale it from another point (the 3D cursor in my case)

[image]

Comment: Also similar to vertices in mesh objects, must select more than one to scale from median.

Comment: Thanks there's a lot more to curves than I thought. https://youtu.be/VLeBsksLCoY and https://youtu.be/Ldccu_OESzc